# Попытка создать проверочное слово (captcha)

Tags: php

Создал веб-форму отправки письма и пытаюсь к ней приделать защиту от спам-ботов. Есть php-код `captcha.php`, что генерирует случайный набор из 6 букв, а также создает графику. Но почему-то графически он не отображается, хотя и прописывается `<img src="/PHP/captcha.php" alt="Verification pass-phrase" />`.  Есть html страница, где отображается эта "защита".

```
<form id="contactForm" action="/PHP/processForm.php" method="post">
    <label for="verify">Проверка:</label>
    <input type="text" id="verify" name="verify"  placeholder="Введите фразу"  />          <img src="/PHP/captcha.php" alt="Verification pass-phrase" />
    <input type="submit" id="sendMessage" name="sendMessage" value="Отправить" />
    <input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Отменить" />
</form>
```

Также есть PHP-страница `processForm.php`, что обробатывет форму и отсылает письмо на почту. Но я не знаю, как мне прописать в этой php-странице функцию проверки:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user_pass_phrase = sha1($_POST['verify']);
    if($_SESSION['pass_phrase'] == $user_pass_phrase);
}
```

Вот `processForm.php`:

```
$sender_Name = $_POST['senderName'];
$sender_Email = $_POST['senderEmail'];
$phone_namber = $_POST['phone'];
$marka_avto = $_POST['marka'];
$message_email = $_POST['message'];
$tel = "Телефон:"; $str = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $tel); 
$eml = "Электронная почта:"; $svr = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $eml); 
$m_av = "Марка автомобиля:"; $mavt = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $m_av);
$wo_rk = "Что нужно сделать:"; $work = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $wo_rk);

$email = '';
$to = '';
$subject = '';
$msg = "$sender_Name  $svr $sender_Email.\n" .
"$str $phone_namber\n" .
"$mavt $marka_avto\n" .
"$work $message_email";  
        $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From:".$email."\n\r";
    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

И стоит ли так делать как я на метил или есть другой вариант? Помогите разобраться!

Answer (score 1):

```
 if($_SESSION['pass_phrase'] == $user_pass_phrase);
```

А если человек отправит форму не со страницы твоего сайта, а с помощью скрипта своего, например? Получится что:

т.к. он не зашел на твою страничку с каптчей, то  $_SESSION['pass_phrase'] не будет существовать. $_POST['verify'] не будет отправлен и получится, что $_POST['verify'] также не существует. (FALSE ==FALSE) ==TRUE. 
Почитайте статьи про капчи, про пути (явно, что у вас изображение не грузится т.к у вас форма отправки тоже лежит в папке PHP ).

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что в данном случае это неудача, особенно, когда речь идет об отправке письма. Так что возражения о `$_SESSION['pass_phrase']`, на мой взгляд, необоснованны. То же касается и `$_POST['verify']`.

Веб-страницы для того и сделаны — чтобы ими пользовались люди (акцент на «ими»). Для скриптов, если это нужно, делают другие интерфейсы.

Comment: Что касается вопроса, так сначала нужно решить ошибку с `$to` (она пустая); устранить проблему с кодировкой; устранить проблему с программистом, который, не находя альтернатив названиям переменных, ведет себя так, будто регистрируется на сервисе, но его ник уже занят.

А корень проблемы с отображением картинки, очевидно, нужно искать в файле "/PHP/captcha.php". Нужно просто в браузере открыть этот файл и посмотреть, что там будет.

Загвоздка может лежать в пределах от «нет GD» до «отдается "text/html; charset=tryagain" вместо "image/jpeg"».

Comment: этот пост был не о неудаче посылки письма, а о неудаче проверки переменной.
А во-вторых зачем тогда каптча, если она не нужна)? Каптча как раз и создается против роботов, а не людей.
"Но я не знаю, как мне прописать в этой php-странице функцию проверки" ... я ему и ответил что не так в его функции проверки.

Comment: Про отправку письма я написал заодно, просто чтобы избежать скучных вопросов в будущем.

Что касается `$_POST['verify']` и `$_SESSION['pass_phrase']` — недоглядел. Прошу прощения за гонор.